# Bug in text selection on Android O?

Tags: text-selection, 8.0-oreo

Nexus 6P, Android O (8.0.0), not rooted.

When I long-press (or double-tap) a word in a textarea field, often the result is that much more than the targeted word is selected. Roughly two lines of text may end up selected. Obviously this makes text selection more difficult, because then I have to use the handles on the selection to resize it to just the word I wanted.

This doesn't occur every time, and I'm having a hard time understanding why/when it does or doesn't occur.

I normally use Swype as my keyboard, but I tried switching to GBoard and saw the same behavior, so I don't think it's related to the keyboard.

I've seen this behavior in Twitter, Fenix (third-party Twitter app) and Google Keep (maybe other apps but I don't remember). But like I said: not always.

I've never had this problem before Android O.

Has anybody observed such a behavior? Is there any known fix for it?

One thing I'm beginning to note as I write this post: this problem doesn't seem to occur if the text is in English; only if the text is in French. It seems a little weird but it's the only criteria that I'm able to discern for now. (I use both languages frequently; I have Android itself set to English.)

Example (screenshot below): long-pressing any word after "montre" (first line) results in this exact selection. Long pressing any word before (and including) "montre" gives the normal result (only one word selected). (In case you're wondering, the selected text has absolutely nothing to do with Google Maps.)

[image: Example of incorrect selection]

**UPDATE**

No solution found yet, but in case it helps somebody, I noticed that once this larger selection is set, you can tap a *third time* on the word you want to select, and then the selection will be reduced to this word. So the problem is not as bad as I first thought. No need to use the selection handles, you just have to tap three times instead of two.